# OAuth 2.0 Using for Google Login: Getting Unknown Host Exception

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to implement Google Login for my webapp [Using OAuth 2.0 for Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login). However, while performing the step 4 ie. "Exchange Code for Access Token and ID Token", when I perform a POST request for the access and ID token, I get the following exception along with the below stacktrace.

java.net.UnknownHostException: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

```
at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:866)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1258)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1211)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1063)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:242)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:130)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:575)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:776)
at dispatch.classic.BlockingHttp$class.dispatch$classic$BlockingHttp$$execute(Http.scala:45)
at dispatch.classic.BlockingHttp$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Http.scala:58)
at dispatch.classic.BlockingHttp$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Http.scala:58)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at dispatch.classic.BlockingHttp$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Http.scala:58)
at dispatch.classic.Http.pack(Http.scala:25)
at dispatch.classic.BlockingHttp$class.execute(Http.scala:53)
at dispatch.classic.Http.execute(Http.scala:21)
at dispatch.classic.HttpExecutor$class.x(executor.scala:36)
at dispatch.classic.Http.x(Http.scala:21)
at dispatch.classic.HttpExecutor$class.when(executor.scala:50)
at dispatch.classic.Http.when(Http.scala:21)
at dispatch.classic.HttpExecutor$class.apply(executor.scala:60)
at dispatch.classic.Http.apply(Http.scala:21)
```

Following are the details of the POST request:

```
import dispatch.classic._
val req = :/("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token").secure
val params = Map(
                  "code" -> code,
                  "client_id" -> googleClientId,
                  "client_secret" -> googleClientSecret,
                  "redirect_uri" -> googleAuthURI,
                  "grant_type" -> "authorization_code"
                )
val res = parse(h(req << params as_str))
```

where,

**code** is the auth code returned in the pervious request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth [Step 2 over [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) ]

**googleAuthURI** is "`https://localhost/portal/google/login`" which is what I have specified in the Google API developer console.

Also I am using scala and [dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) to implement this.

Comment: How about `val req = url(https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token)`?

Comment: can you help me in getting authorization code, i have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with how dispatch finds out the hostname from the request url. In this case

val req = :/("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token").secure

Dispatch interprets the hostname as "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" which is not available and hence it throws an exception. To counter this we need to structure the req url as,

val req = :/("accounts.google.com"/"o"/"oauth2"/"token").secure